# How Do I Replicate Computed Field Functionality In Drupal 8?

Tags: entities

I have a question regarding Computed Values in Drupal 8. I currently use Computed Fields in Drupal 7 to perform mathematical operations on certain fields and save that calculation in another field. I am attempting to recreate this functionality in a Drupal 8 install.

I recently saw an article that said Computed Fields would be depreciated by the functionality of Drupal 8 core. However, it is not clear to me how to recreate this in Drupal 8. Could someone explain how I take one integer field and multiply it by a percentage to get a decimal number?

I would appreciate any help provided.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: can you link this article you are talking about? 
I don't think there's such a feature in D8 core at the moment...

Answer (score 3):

There you are:

https://drupal.org/node/2112677

Basically you have to write a plugin and store your calculations in the getValue() function.